# what's the simplest framebuffer example for opengl?

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

im trying to add post processing to my game but i can't understand the framebuffer tutorial on learnopengl and opengl-tutorial i just need a simple framebuffer example with color and depth textures and how to use it and render it

im not sure how to implement a framebuffer

```
  public class FrameBuffer
    {
        public int FBO,DBO;
        public int Width, Height;
        public int tex,depth;

        public FrameBuffer(int width, int height)
        {
            this.Width = width;
            this.Height = height;

            FBO = GL.GenFramebuffer();
            Bind();

            tex = GL.GenTexture();
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, tex);
            GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgb, Width, Height, 0, PixelFormat.Rgb, PixelType.UnsignedByte, (IntPtr)null);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Nearest);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Nearest);

            GL.FramebufferTexture2D(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, FramebufferAttachment.ColorAttachment0, TextureTarget.Texture2D, tex, 0);
        }
        public void Bind()
        {
            GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, FBO);
        }
        public void Unbind()
        {
            GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code sets up a proper framebuffer with a color plane.

If the framebufer has to have a depth buffer, then you've to create a depth texture, with the format [`PixelFormat.DepthComponent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/opentk.graphics.es30.pixelformat?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) and one of the internal formats `PixelInternalFormat.DepthComponent16`, `PixelInternalFormat.DepthComponent24`, `PixelInternalFormat.DepthComponent32` or `PixelInternalFormat.DepthComponent32f`:

```cs
depth = GL.GenTexture();
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, depth);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D,
                TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Nearest);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D,
                TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Nearest);

GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.DepthComponent24,
              Width, Height, 0, PixelFormat.DepthComponent, PixelType.Float, (IntPtr)null);
```

Attach it to the framebuffer, to [`FramebufferAttachment.DepthAttachment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/opentk.graphics.es30.framebufferattachment?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)

```cs
GL.FramebufferTexture2D(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer,
                        FramebufferAttachment.DepthAttachment,
                        TextureTarget.Texture2D, depth, 0);
```

Note after you've attached the color buffer and the depth buffer you should validate the framebuffer completeness, which should return a `status` value of `FramebufferErrorCode.FramebufferComplete`.:

```cs
FramebufferErrorCode status = GL.CheckFramebufferStatus(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer);
```

---

Alternatively to a depth texture you can attach a (depth) renderbuffer:

```cs
depth = GL.GenRenderbuffer();
GL.BindRenderbuffer(RenderbufferTarget.Renderbuffer, depth);
GL.RenderbufferStorage(RenderbufferTarget.Renderbuffer,
                       RenderbufferStorage.DepthComponent24, Width, Height);
GL.BindRenderbuffer(RenderbufferTarget.Renderbuffer, 0);

GL.FramebufferRenderbuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, 
                           FramebufferAttachment.DepthAttachment,
                           RenderbufferTarget.Renderbuffer, depth);
```

Comment: do you have a full example, im still having trouble trying to figure out how to use this

Comment: @vincentcastro Your example sets up a complete framebuffer. I showed you hoe to add a depth buffer. What do you mean by *"how to use this"*? This is unclear. What does not work? What do try to achieve? I can copy my code in the middle of your code - but I don't think this is what you are asking for.

Comment: i mean im not sure how i would display it im still new to opengl

Comment: @vincentcastro You can use the texture is attached to the framebuffer to draw a new geometry, e.g. a quad (rectangle) on the entire screen or you can use [`glBlitFramebuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glBlitFramebuffer.xhtml) to copy the content of the framebuffer directly to the screen (default framebuffer).